# About Graph API of Facebook Places

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i can not see good documentation about Facebook Places, please tell me if you know something about it.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,122.427&distance=1000

1) In above url what is the unit of distance? (Meter, KM, Miles or something else?)

2) What is the actual meaning of distance.. is it search result comes within this range or it starts search within this range and goes beyond for more results?

3) How can we restrict search result to any specific city or country?

4) What we can do more with this API?

Comment: The url above won't get any data, but I suspect you meant this:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dcoffee%26type%3Dplace%26center%3D37.76%2C-122.427%26distance%3D1000

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-nearby-places/ the unit of distance is meters.

   - edit - FB keeps moving the information around their documentation, so it may not be there when you look. Search for 'places meters' and you should find the citation: https://developers.facebook.com/search/?q=places%20meters
2. The search excludes results outside of a circle with the radius of your specific distance.
3. Use the location field of the places returned by your search to filter out any unwanted places.  For example, if you had these results, you could use the city filter to include only Brooklyn (or New York).

`[{
      "name": "Bembe", 
      "location": {
        "street": "81 S 6th St.", 
        "city": "Brooklyn", 
        "state": "NY", 
        "country": "United States", 
        "zip": "11222", 
        "latitude": 40.710978587859, 
        "longitude": -73.965404723282
      }, 
      "id": "146207358735488"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Manhattan Bridge Orthodontics", 
      "location": {
        "street": "145 Canal St, 2nd Floor", 
        "city": "New York", 
        "state": "NY", 
        "country": "United States", 
        "zip": "10002-5033", 
        "latitude": 40.709716414644, 
        "longitude": -73.988593034059
      }, 
      "id": "121071754616533"
    }]`

4.Limited only by your imagination.

Comment: Is there other filters we can put there other than q, center and distance? Yes indeed Facebook keeps moving stuff around, and there seems no clear documentation on the allowable search query strings