# search events by local at facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I`d like to get all events (from facebook) that will happen at a specific place.

for example:
Me, and two others people creating events in different days at a place X.
I need to get all info about the events created by me and others for that place.

Comment: You can search for events, you just need the places coordinates and a radius. Don't know dev doc url, but google might help you.

Comment: Maybe this one will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413320/about-graph-api-of-facebook-places